# Importing contacts from yahoo using API

Tags: php, mysql, yahoo, yahoo-api

I'm trying to find any tutorial or resources to import contacts from Yahoo and/or live mail using their API (not using cURL). For example, you are asked to authenticate via Yahoo and then you can select the contacts(emails) to import.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You can import YAHOO Contacts from this API page  https://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/